# How do you automatically insert column name of table1 into table2 whenever data inside table1's column gets updated in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

table1:

```
| name | address |
| ---- | ------- |
| John | brazil  |
```

table1 when address is updated:

```
| name | address   |
| ---- | -------   |
| John | argentina |
```

as soon as table1 is updated, desired automatic insert on
table2:

```
| updated_column_of_table1 |
| ------------------------ |
| address                  |
```

Suppose somebody updated the table1 information without my knowledge such as address of john to 'Argentina' and let's say i don't know in which column the update was done. What I want is whenever somebody updates the values inside any of the column of table1, the name of that updated column has to be inserted into another table consider 'table2'. How do you do that in postgresql? Sorry for my english.
Thanks in advance.